# Read URL API with php

Tags: php, json

One of URL's return JSON format that start like this

```
[
{ "name" : "Some Name",
  "price":  "20"

} ]
```

How can i read this type of Json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$json = '[
{ "name" : "Some Name",
  "price":  "20"

} ]';



$json = json_decode($json,true);

echo $json[0]['name'];
echo $json[0]['price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode`

```
$data = '[{"name":"Some Name", "price":"20"}]';
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach($data as $output){
    echo $output->name;
}
```